# HTML5 Simple Video Player. What did I miss?

Tags: html, video, html5-video

First I made a screen recording as a video I would like to display.

Than I uploaded the video to VLC to convert the video.

I made one MP4 and a fallback for OGG.

I then moved the videos to my dropbox account so I can host them there.I right clicked and got the link to each video from dropbox. I am trying to use the links as the src in the video tags.

```
<video width="400" controls>
  <source src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/m7emkfs994sgm5g/Untitled.m4v?dl=0" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/9owwdbm8p0nz1f0/oggguntitled.ogg?dl=0" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

Even though I told VLC to convert it to MPV, the file extension is m4v.. Is that the same thing?

The video just shows blank. Not getting any errors either.Not sure what I missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following Fixed it for me.

I made two changes:

- change `dl=0` at the end of your dropbox link to `dl=1`. I believe this makes it a download link instead of a page to view a download link.
- Due to a bug in chrome on OSX certain `mp4` files will fail to play correctly (some kind of graphics acceleration issue), but it won't fall back to the `ogv`. For this reason, i have placed the `ogv` as first since it will work on OSX-chrome, and platforms that don't support it **should** fall back to the mp4.

```html
<video width="400" controls>

  <source src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/9owwdbm8p0nz1f0/oggguntitled.ogg?dl=1" type="video/ogg">
    <source src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/m7emkfs994sgm5g/Untitled.m4v?dl=1" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Interesting. Not sure how you knew to add `dl=1`

The video now seems to appear however when it uses the `ogg` type it appears that it is disabling audio. Any advice on this?

Comment: That must be an encoding issue. Check the recommended settings for html5 video and `VLC`